# Pass QueryString parameter to Reporting Services 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a reporting service report that accepts a parameter. I am trying to pass the parameter as follows:

```
http://localhost/ReportsServer/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSalesReports%2fReport1&CustomerID=3
```

The above seems not to work. Any idea?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pointing to the server directly:

`http://localhost/ReportsServer?%2fSalesReports%2fReport1&CustomerID=3`

Comment: Actually, I should be using Reporting Service not Server. It works now smooth. Thank you.